# Android Multiple Screen Resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a android layout that looks fine on my Galaxy s2 (480×800) device. I want to support a layout for and Galaxy s3 (720x1280) so i created a AVD with those specs, then copied the res/layout directory and contents to two other directories: res/layout, res/layout-large and res/layout-xlarge. To test that the layouts were working positioned a test button at parent-center in res/layout, parent-left in res/layout-large and parent-right in res/layout-xlarge. If i run the application on my device (480×800) or in the AVD (720x1280) the test button is always at parent-center. Why isn't the test button positioned by the values specified in res/layout-large or res/layout-xlarge.

My manifest is as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<supports-screens 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I am targeting 2.3.3 and have also cleaned my build before testing

Im seriously going mad so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your manifest was not included..

Comment: the S2 and S3 arent large screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Galaxy S3 is a "large" screen. Small/normal/large/xlarge refer to physical size, not pixels. You need a combination of screen density and screen size to target different devices. Read the Android [guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [training](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) for more details on this.

Comment: So how do i get the layout to look the same on the s2 and s3

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "look the same". If you're using `dp` and `sp` values as you should be (as opposed to `px`), the same layout should look pretty close on both devices, although the different aspect ratio will probably change things a little.

Comment: No they are totally different. If i resize the images fit the s3 then they are massive for the s2. If i resize the images fit for the s2 then they only go half way across the screen for the s3. Im using dp for all my dimensions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: check this link out where it says Configuration Examples: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Comment: @user346443 You'll have to post some code and/or layouts (and maybe screenshots showing the differences in results) for more specific help.